# Help with calculating discrete expected values

Tags: probability

What should you pay your friend if the sum of the two dice is not divisible by 3 in order to play a fair game. Where the expected value value is 0 in order for it to be fair.

The sample space consists of 36 possibilities of which only 11 are divisible by 3:

$(1,2),(1,5),(2,1),(2,4),(3,3),(3,6),(4,2),(4,5),(5,1),(5,4),(6,3),(6,6)$

This leaves a probability of $\frac{12}{36}=\frac{1}{3}$

Therefore the probability of obtaining dice not divisible by 3 = $\frac{24}{36}=\frac{1}{3}$

So the payment for the expected value 0 would be:

$0= \frac{1}{3} \times $6+ \frac{2}{3} \times x = [-6=2x]=[x=3]$

The payment for a fair game would be $3.

The night watchman in a factory cannot guard both the safe in back and the cash register in front.
The safe contains $6000, while the register has only $1000. Tonight the guard fears a robbery; the
probability that the thief will try the cash register is 0.8 and the probability the thief will try the
safe is 0.2. If the guard is not present, the thief will take all the money. If the guard is present, the
thief will go away empty handed. Where should the guard be positioned in order to minimize the
thief's gains?

Let X denote the amount the thief gets away with:

Then $E[X]=$ Probability the owner does not guard the safe does not times the probability the thief chooses the safe times the value of the safe plus the probability the owner does not guard the register times the probability the thief chooses the register times the value of the safe.

So $E[X]= [.5 \times .2 \times 6000]+[.5 \times .8 \times 1000]$= $600+400= 1000$ Which means the guard should watch the register since the expected value is not greater than the register. Did I model this correctly and use the correct logic?

Comment: Use `$\$$` for $\$$.

Comment: why is my question down voted?

Comment: There are a number of probable reasons.  First, you should only be asking one question per post.  The question involving dice and divisibility by three is completely and totally unrelated to the question about thieves and the factory guard.  Second, your title is nondescriptive and could be greatly improved to be about the specific question you have.  Third, you have obvious typos that should have been caught as you were typing, for example $\frac{24}{36}=\frac{1}{3}$ and how dollar signs begin or end mathmode having you write things like "$6000,whiletheregisterhasonly$1000"

Comment: Once those are fixed, you have actually done quite a few things correctly in your post, so I am willing to upvote (*though I still recommend splitting this into two separate questions instead of one*).  You did make an attempt and showed your work.  I encourage you to continue that in the future.

Comment: The first question is unfortunately ambiguously worded in its current form.  I can gather that you wish to play a betting game against your friend, and the winner is determined based on whether or not the sum of two dice is a multiple of three.  It sounds as though the cost of playing is trying to be determined, however it is not currently stated what the amount of money you win would be.  The answer of how much would be a fair cost will vary based on that.  At the extreme, if you win \$0, you shouldn't pay anything to play.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is ambiguously worded and seems like it may be missing information.

> "What should you pay your friend if the sum of the two dice is not divisible by 3 in order to play a fair game. Where the expected value value is 0 in order for it to be fair."

As mentioned in the comments above, you seem to be missing how much you are slated to win if the dice go in your favor... and it is ambiguous as well whether you hope for the dice to *be* a multiple of three, or whether you hope the dice will *not be* a multiple of three to win.

I'll reword the question to a form that I think actually makes sense:

> You and your friend want to play a betting game using dice.  You pay $k$ dollars to play.  Two fair six-sided dice are thrown and the sum of the dice is looked at.  If the sum of the dice is a multiple of three, you win and your friend pays you $w$ dollars.  Otherwise you lose.  Given a specific value of $w$, what should the value of $k$ be to make the game fair?

(*Note: in the above wording you get a total of $w$ back if you win.  You do not make a net profit of $w$, but rather you get a net profit of $w-k$ if you win.  Compare this to the phrasing of the problem where you get $w$ for winning /and/ your buy-in back*)

To begin, you are correct that we need to determine the probability of winning and losing.  You are correct that one of the methods to do this would be to look at the thirty-six equally likely outcomes of the pair of dice and see how many of those have the sum totaling a multiple of three.  This is however a very tedious approach.

One of the main points of an introductory course in combinatorics or probability is learning how to count things and approach problems in ways *other* than using brute force.  Here, you should recognize that if you imagine that the dice are thrown one after the other, regardless of what the result of the first die happened to be, exactly two of the six outcomes of the second die will result in the sum being a multiple of three.

As such, we learn that the probability of winning will be $\frac{1}{3}$.

From this we further learn that the probability of losing will be $\frac{2}{3}$

Now... we try to figure out what the expected value of the game will be.  If you win, you will have lost $k$ dollars in order to begin playing but you will have later gotten $w$ dollars back for having won.  If you lose, you will have only lost $k$ dollars.  Letting $X$ represent the random variable for how much you are expected to win:

$E[X]=(w-k)\frac{1}{3}+(-k)\frac{2}{3}$

To make the game fair, we set this equal to zero and we can then try to solve for $k$

$0=(w-k)\frac{1}{3}+(-k)\frac{2}{3}\implies k=\frac{1}{3}w$

For example, if your friend was going to give you $6$ dollars if you won you should only pay $2$ dollars to play.

(*Think of it this way, if you are expected to win a third of the time, if you play three games you are expected to have won once and lost the other two.  Paying 2 dollars three times and getting back six dollars one of those times will average out*)

(*Note: if you were to get back you buyin in addition to the winning amount if you won, then instead of $E[X]=(w-k)\frac{1}{3}+(-k)\frac{2}{3}$ it would have instead been $E[X]=(w)\frac{1}{3}+(-k)\frac{2}{3}$.  That however is not how problems like these are commonly worded.*)

---

For the second problem, glossing over some of the details, the guard has essentially two strategies: either watch the safe, or watch the register.

If the guard decides to watch the register then the expected amount he will *lose* is $E[X] = 0\times 0.8\times 1000 + 1\times 0.2\times 6000=1200$

If the guard decides to watch the safe then the expected amount he will lose is $E[X]=1\times 0.8\times 1000 + 0\times 0.2\times 6000 = 800$

Either way, he should expect to lose some money, but the expected losses are minimized if he chooses to watch the safe instead of the register, so he should do that.

The longer and more involved answer is that there is technically a third strategy: the guard can choose randomly which to guard with probability $p$ to guard the safe and probability $1-p$ to guard the register.  In some problems, a mixture of the two would actually be a better strategy.  In particular, if we did not already know the theif's strategy ahead of time (*i.e. if we didn't know the probabilities that the thief will go to each spot*).  Read up on the topic of [game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) for a more involved discussion of the full problem.